# Linux - Limit user's ftp access to home directory

Tags: linux, ftp, user, home-directory

I have created a user in linux (User1 for the purpose of this question). I have changed User1's home directory to a new directory. I would like to ensure that User1, when FTP'ing, cannot browse out of their home directory but can still browse deeper into it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to tell us which FTP server you're running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause your FTP server process to chroot the user to their home directory. This is an option in most popular FTP daemons.